# how to show image after fetching from firebase

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi, firebase-storage

I am trying to fetch image from firebase storage using python into my raspberry pi 3.

```
    import urllib.request 
    URL=urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cameraviewer-32936.appspot.com/o/images%2F49567?alt=media&token=1eded9d0-b9f0-48bf-b869-37756b31a94a")
```

URL object has a few key value pairs. One of them was 'str' with value of:

```
'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4ki4w7we'
```

The above value represents the path of image fetched into my device But how can i open image. I don't know where to go or am I confused a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple using **Python Imaging Library (PIL)**. PIL is free and open-source library.

## How to Install PIL

If you don't have PILLOW installed, first open a **terminal** ( *CTRL + ALT + T* ) and download it using **command**:

```
sudo pip install Pillow
```

## Displaying an Image

After you successfully installed it, use the code below to show your downloaded image:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request 

URL=urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cameraviewer-32936.appspot.com/o/images%2F49567?alt=media&token=1eded9d0-b9f0-48bf-b869-37756b31a94a")
img = Image.open(URL[0])
img.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But the problem is response from line 3 of your code is  having many name value pairs. One key is 'str' and has value of 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4ki4w7we'. I will be fetching from different URLs and hence this value of str will change on every iteration of reading from server. You have manually put thisvalue in Image.open(). How do i overcome this?

Comment: Plus, i am getting below error on executing your above syntax: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Try the edited last example please, and let me know if any problem occurs.